# SOQL select archived product2 records

Tags: soql, data, product

There are some records in one of the custom objects that relate (lookup) to archived product2 records.

I am unable to select archived Prodcut2 records even though I can access them via UI... I am using simple SOQL statement, followed by "ALL ROWS" option.

```
SELECT id FROM product2 WHERE id = '<archivedId>' ALL ROWS --Returns 0
```

Error description: "copado.tango.data.advanced.deployment.exception.IdNotFoundInDestinationRecordsException"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you running this from? I see copado in the error description. Your query looks fine and will work. You can test if it works by doing it in:

1. anonymous apex
2. workbench (select include for "deleted and archived records")
3. data loader

However, it's important to note the "ALL ROWS" won't work if you're running it through the query editor in dev console (as it runs it through a REST API call). You can upvote/see this [idea here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DpgiAAC).